# How to make belongsTo relation work in loopback4

Tags: mongodb, loopback4

i'm trying to use loopback4 belongsTo relation but i get the same error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

## source model

every room should have a type

```
export class Rooms extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
  })
  _id: string;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
  })
  rating?: number;

// relation ###
  @belongsTo(() => RoomsTypes)
  roomsTypesId: string;



  constructor(data?: Partial<Rooms>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

## target model

the room types model

```
@model({settings: {strict: false}})
export class RoomsTypes extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
  })
  _id: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  numOfPeople: number;

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  features: string[];


  constructor(data?: Partial<RoomsTypes>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

## source repository

i think that the error is here

```
import {
  DefaultCrudRepository,
  juggler,
  repository,
  BelongsToAccessor,
} from '@loopback/repository';
import { Rooms, RoomsRelations, RoomsTypes, RoomsTypesRelations} from '../models';
import {inject, Getter} from '@loopback/core';

import { RoomsTypesRepository } from './rooms-types.repository';

export class RoomsRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  Rooms,
  typeof Rooms.prototype._id,
  RoomsRelations
> {
  public readonly roomTypes: BelongsToAccessor<
  RoomsTypes,
    typeof Rooms.prototype._id
  >;
  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.db')  protected DbDataSource: juggler.DataSource,
    @repository.getter('RoomsTypesRepository')
    RoomsTypesRepositoryGetter: Getter<RoomsTypesRepository>,
  ) {

    super(Rooms, DbDataSource);
    this.roomTypes = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor(
      'roomsTypesId',
      RoomsTypesRepositoryGetter,
    );
  }
}
```

i get the same error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

When creating a `createBelongsToAccessorFor` you need to specify the relation name, not the relation id:

```
this.roomTypes = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor('roomsTypesId', RoomsTypesRepositoryGetter);
```

should be

```
this.roomTypes = this.createBelongsToAccessorFor('roomTypes', RoomsTypesRepositoryGetter);
```

Additionally should be mentioned that loopback has some asumptions to the naming of properties which are used for relations. For example the `ID` of an relation is constructed by the `ModelName` + `Id`. This is also used for lookup the target model.

If you need a different naming, you need to specify `keyTo` or `keyFrom` in the relation definition.

The [official documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/BelongsTo-relation.html) was recently updated with a detailed description and examples of the `@belongsTo` relation:

> The @belongsTo decorator takes three parameters:
>
> - target model class (required)
> - relation definition (optional) - has three attributes, keyFrom, keyTo, name
>
>   - `keyFrom` is the property name of the foreign key on the “source” model. It is always set to the decorated property name (in the given
>       example it is, “customerId” property on Order model).
>   - `keyTo` is the property name of the foreign key on the “target” model, it is typically the primary key of the “target” model. keyTo
>       attribute defaults to the id property on the target model (in the
>       given example, “id” property on Customer).
>   - `name` is the name of the relation as defined in the repository. The relation name is used in the repository constructor to define a
>       BelongsToAccessor and map it to the relation using a inclusion
>       resolver.
> - `property definition` (optional) - creates a property decorator implicitly. The name attribute in the definition can be used to customize datasource column name.